# Why am I getting the error 'Connection pool for {host} was cleared because another operation failed'?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I have a cron job in NestJs that should delete users who haven't been verified for 12 hours (the cron is set to run every hour). However, I occasionally see the following errors in the console:

[image]

These errors occur intermittently. There is only one 'users' table in the MongoDB database with 2 records, so the database is not overloaded. Im used free cloud from mongodb com

Here's the code:

```
  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_HOUR, {
    name: 'cleanUnverifiedUsers',
  })
  async cleanUnverifiedUsers() {
    try {
      const twelveHoursAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

      await this.userModel.deleteMany({
        is_verified_email: false,
        created_at: { $lte: twelveHoursAgo },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // logic
    }
  }
```

Why is this problem occurring, and how can it be fixed?